# Why is a resistor frequency independent?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, frequency

I had a doubt that why is a resistor, frequency independent? Since, as frequency increases the movement of electrons increases so heat increases which causes change in resistance. So my question is why a resistor offers same resistance to every frequency. Any Clarification on this is appreciated.

Comment: That is just a simplifying assumption; which matches reality in small frequencies pretty well.

Comment: means resistance does change with frequencies

Answer (score 11):

An ideal resistor is *defined* as the two-terminal circuit element where the voltage across is proportional to the current through:

$V_R = R \cdot I_R$

and the constant of proportionality, $R$, is, well, *constant*.

A physical resistor has at least series inductance and parallel capacitance and can be modelled with ideal circuit elements as follows (for example):

[image]

So, a physical resistor has an associated $Q$ and resonance frequency, i.e., it is frequency dependent.

In radio frequency (RF) design, the frequencies of interest are high enough that the frequency dependence must be taken into account.

At much lower frequencies, e.g., audio frequencies, the frequency dependence can, in general, be ignored.

Comment: I once read in the feynman's lecture that at high frequencies an coil has a capacity and a capacity has a certain inductance. Is there any references on this and on what you said?

Comment: @metacompactness, that's correct.  Above the resonance frequency, an inductor becomes capacitive and a capacitor becomes inductive.  See, for example, this:  http://www.cliftonlaboratories.com/self-resonant_frequency_of_inductors.htm

Comment: I was under the impression that the question want to know whether frequency changes can increase the resistance of the 'resistive element' (R) in the diagram that you drew.
And if so, is that because of the movement of electrons and heat generated by that?

Comment: @user1218748, the OP wrote:  *So my question is why a resistor offers same resistance to every frequency.*  I answered "it doesn't" and then I explained why.

Comment: so during radio-freq analysis we consider impedance of resistor as wR or 1/wR..

Comment: @MithileshShah, using the schematic in my answer above, observe that the impedance of the resistor is:  $sL + R || \frac{1}{sC}$

Answer (score 0):

A higher frequency does not mean that the average drift speed ("movement") of the electrons increases. The average drift speed, which depends on the mean free path, stays constant.

Comment: It would be better to add a little more information.

Answer (score -2):

Electrical resistance is the opposition to current flowing in the circuit, while the reactance is the opposition to change in current in term of capacitance and inductance
So when frequency is change current is change and when current is change it's became reactance not resistance although both have same units...
So the behaviour of resistance is independent of frequency...
I think so...

Comment: The question asked if _resistors_ are frequency independent, not _resistance_.  As highlighted well in the other answer, resist**ors** will have some non-ideal behavior, especially at high frequencies where the inductance and capacitance of the components is induced.  Just as an aside, you can also consider resistance and reactance together as [impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance).

Answer (score -3):

The resistor only limits the flow of current not with $\partial I/\partial t$ example inductor it will opposes the flow of current when it will change with time means time i.e $T=\frac1f$ so frequency changes take in inductor that's why resistor is frequency independent inductor frequency dependent.

$V=IR$, but Inductor $\mathrm{e.m.f}=-L \displaystyle{\frac{\partial I}{\partial t}}$